# 2016 dodge grand caravan transmission, overfilled solenoid issues

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, dodge, grand-caravan

I have a 2016 dodge grand Caravan I had the transmission replaced six months ago then just had a new engine put in it got it back drove it for 3-4 days noticed it started to wine took it back to the same shop. They said it was overfilled. They’re the only ones that have worked on it would that cause the solenoids to go bad the transmission was slipping and whining

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!